# EF 4 inherited class how to query my child class

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ado.net

How to have an IEnumerable result of my child class in EF 4. Like, I have an ObjectSet for my base class an EntitySet too .. but for my child I have no way to query them .. Whit some try an error I succeed to Read, Update, Create, Delete .. but not to query (or list) my child class..

I Read like this :

> ```
>     public Member GetMember(Guid id)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             using (EntitiesContainer db = new EntitiesContainer())
>             {
>                 return db.Resources.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id) as Member;
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             Log entry = new Log();
>             entry.ClassName = GetType().Name;
>             entry.Message = ex.Message;
>             entry.MethodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
>             entry.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
>             _logger.Log(entry, SeverityEnum.Critical);
>         }
>
>         return new Member();
>     }
> ```

I Create like this :

> ```
>     public Member CreateMember(Member member, string userName)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             using (EntitiesContainer db = new EntitiesContainer())
>             {
>                 member.Id = (Guid)_userService.GetUser(userName).ProviderUserKey;
>
>                 db.Resources.AddObject(member);
>
>                 db.SaveChanges();
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             Log entry = new Log();
>             entry.ClassName = GetType().Name;
>             entry.Message = ex.Message;
>             entry.MethodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
>             entry.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
>             _logger.Log(entry, SeverityEnum.Critical);
>         }
>
>         return member;
>     }
> ```

I Update like this :

> ```
>     public Member UpdateMember(Member member)
>     {
>         try
>         {
>             using (EntitiesContainer db = new EntitiesContainer())
>             {
>                 db.Resources.Attach(GetMember(member.Id));
>
>                 db.Resources.ApplyCurrentValues(member);
>
>                 db.SaveChanges();
>             }
>         }
>         catch (Exception ex)
>         {
>             Log entry = new Log();
>             entry.ClassName = GetType().Name;
>             entry.Message = ex.Message;
>             entry.MethodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
>             entry.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
>             _logger.Log(entry, SeverityEnum.Critical);
>         }
>
>         return member;
>     }
> ```

And so on...

But for list or query my Members Collection or ObjectSet ... I have no way for doing this.

I try something like that .. but it return me null or a casting exception.

> ```
>    public IEnumerable<Member> GetAll()
>    {
>        try
>        {
>            using (EntitiesContainer db = new EntitiesContainer())
>            {
>                var test = db.Resources.ToList() as IList<Member>;
>
>                // OR
>
>                var test = db.Resources as IEnumerable<Member>;
>
>                // OR
>
>                var test = db.Resources.Cast<Member>();
>
>                // OR
>
>                var test = db.Resources.AsEnumerable<Member>();    
>
>                return test;
>            }
>        }
>        catch (System.Exception ex)
>        {
>            Log entry = new Log();
>            entry.ClassName = GetType().Name;
>            entry.Message = ex.Message;
>            entry.MethodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
>            entry.StackTrace = ex.StackTrace;
>            _logger.Log(entry, SeverityEnum.Critical);
>        }
>
>        return null;
>    }
> ```

I Try to create an ObjectSet for my Member too but they throw me that i dont have any EntitySet for this ObjectSet .. that its logicly right ..

But I see in debugging that there an instance of DynamicProxies of the my Member .. an this properties is right with the good value .. but i dont know how to reach it .. I can believe that EF team they have not think for that ... I search everywhere in the net .. no sucess .. I need an expert :) !

Thank you a lot for your time! I appreciate!

Cordialy,
Julien.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EntitiesContainer db = new EntitiesContainer();
var members = db.Resources.OfType<Member>();
```